# Swift set attribute to auto increment

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm building my first app with Swift 3 and Xcode 8.3.1. I have insert also a CoreDataModel with one Entity.

This Entity have these attributes:

> id int16
>
> description String
>
> pin int16

Now I want to set at auto increment the attribute "id", it is possibile to do this? Or how can I get the max ID from this Entity and then set it?

Comment: FetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"entityName"
    inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id==max(id)"];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray array];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]

Comment: @Gagan_iOS thanks for your answer but this is the method that I should to add at my CoreDataController.swift?

Comment: you have to write the code in swift language not Objc. Sorry I posted in ObjC.

Comment: ah ok, but in what class I should to write this code?

Comment: where you want to populate/get the max value preferably in yourViewController.swift file.

Comment: Unrelated issue: don't name your attribute "description": it conflicts with the standard NSManagedObject "description" property, and you will get some strange results.

Comment: The objects in core data have an internal id. Normally you don't need an extra id. Can you describe what you want to archive with an id?